# Is Material UI for React free?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is Material UI (for react application) free? We are planning to use it in our application but before that need to check for any licensing issues. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The answer is yes https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: @keikai Thanks for the info.

Comment: At my work we just found there are some components that require a premium subscription. Such as nested accordion rows in a table. Be careful when decided to tie your project with MUI.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's free.

It's using an MIT License, so it's free even for commercial use. It uses the same license as React. See https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/LICENSE.

Answer (score 11):

The release of Material UI v5 comes with new components, released under an extension product: [MUI X](https://mui.com/x/). These components in MUI X are not entirely free (open-source) but there are open-core. For example, the Data Grid: https://mui.com/pricing/ has some of its features MIT while others are Commercial.